# Angularjs Tooltip Directive Jquery Independent

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

I want to create a tooltip in angularjs `without` using jquery or bootstrap.

I tried to make a directive where I try to find the `x`, `y` position of the `parent` where tooltip directive is placed. This is my `link` function.

```
element.parent().css('position', 'relative');

left = offset(element.parent()).left;
right = offset(element.parent()).right; 

function offset(elm) { 
  try {return elm.offset();} catch(e) {} 
  var rawDom = elm[0]; 
  var _x = 0; 
  var _y = 0; 
  var body = document.documentElement || document.body; 
  var scrollX = window.pageXOffset || body.scrollLeft; 
  var scrollY = window.pageYOffset || body.scrollTop; 
  _x = rawDom.getBoundingClientRect().left + scrollX; 
  _y = rawDom.getBoundingClientRect().top + scrollY; 
  return { left: _x, top:_y }; 
}
```

But left and right are always coming to be zero.

I couldn't find a tooltip without jquery or bootstrap dependency online. Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: you can check this one tho https://github.com/720kb/angular-tooltips which doesnt seems to require jquery at all

Answer (score 0):

I made a tooltip library for angularJS.
It might be a good start even though it's using JQuery for things like removing and showing.

https://github.com/jeremistadler/angular-tooltip